# How to specify vcovHC option within Fstats function (strucchange package)?

Tags: r

In the example below I use the vcovHC option to generate robust standard errors for a standard linear model. Using this same example, I tried to generate the distribution of F statistics with robust standard errors using the Fstats() function. The problem is that Fstats uses vcovHC internally as shown in the bottom line of the code below (which I extracted from the Fstats function).

```
else {
      allX <- cbind(X1, matrix(rep(0, point[i]*k), ncol=k))
      allX <- rbind(allX, cbind(X2, X2))
      fm2 <- lm(y ~ 0 + allX)
      beta2 <- coef(fm2)[-(1:k)]
      V <- vcov.(fm2)
```

I don't know how to specify the vcovHC option when using the Fstats() function. What I did try (see below) does not work. Thank you for your help.

```
rm(list = ls())
> 
> library(lmtest)
> library(sandwich)
> library(strucchange)
> 
> y <- as.ts(c(4,3,-2,1,-4,0,1,-2,-3,2,0,1,-2,2,4,1,3,5,2,2,3,4))
> X <- as.ts(rep(1,22))
> 
> # lm model with robust standard errors
> model<- lm(y ~ X - 1)
> coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, type = "HC0"))

t test of coefficients:

  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
X  1.13636    0.51545  2.2046  0.03877 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> 
> # Fstats model with regular standard errors
> model2 <- Fstats(y ~ X - 1, from = 3, to = 18)
> model2$Fstats
Time Series:
Start = 3 
End = 18 
Frequency = 1 
 [1]  0.1530982  0.1010540  0.5609994  0.8631524  0.8332749  2.2221599  5.5956726
 [8]  4.5129612  5.6715064  5.8951319 11.4357216 10.2821317  6.1921347  7.1910292
[15]  5.4546513  2.1974238
> 
 # Fstats model with robust standard errors
> model3 <- Fstats(y ~ X - 1, from = 3, to = 18, vcovHC(.,type = "HC0"))
Error in vcovHC(., type = "HC0") : object '.' not found
```

Comment: As the error says, you are passing `.` as the first argument to `vcovHC`, but there is no such object as `.` . Perhaps you want `Fstats(y ~ X - 1, from = 3, to = 18, vcovHC(model, type = "HC0"))` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Replacing the "." with "model" doesn't work, regardless of whether I change the name of the first regression away from "model". I have spent a lot of time searching for how to do this but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vcov` argument in `Fstats()` needs to be a function (see `?Fstats`) because it has to be applied to a whole range of different linear models fitted to subsets of the data. This is in contrast to `coeftest()` where it can either be a function or a matrix because it is just combined with a single model.

A worked example is included in the `durab` data set, providing the growth rate of the Industrial Production Index to average weekly labor hours in the manufacturing/durables sector. The example is taken from Hansen (2001) and uses a simple AR(1) model:

```
library("strucchange")
data("durab", package = "strucchange")
fsHC <- Fstats(y ~ lag, data = durab, from = 0.1,
  vcov = function(x, ...) vcovHC(x, type = "HC", ...))
plot(fsHC)
sctest(fsHC)
##      supF test
## 
## data:  fsHC
## sup.F = 20.221, p-value = 0.001371
```

Note also that for the classical HC sandwich estimator you can use `sandwich()` rather than `vcovHC(..., type = "HC0")`. Thus, using `vcov = sandwich` in the code above is simpler than setting up a new function on the fly.